Issue with Azure CLI Authentication on Virtual Machine: Access Currently Unavailable Error
Using Terraform, I created an architecture for my project and connected via Azure CLI from the terminal successfully. However, when I created a virtual machine, installed Azure CLI on it, and tried to connect to my Azure account using Azure CLI, I encountered an issue. After entering the provided code at https://microsoft.com/devicelogin, I received the following error message:
"Access currently unavailable Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you may be signing in from a browser, application, or location restricted by your administrator."
Despite using an email provided by my engineering school, when I tried to go to Azure Active Directory to check the policies of my Azure account, I encountered the message "You do not have access | Overview". I suspect that the virtual machine is running in the US, and my account policies might not allow me to access it. However, I'm not certain if this is the root cause of the problem  can someone help me in this problem please ?


"Access currently unavailable Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you may be signing in from a browser, application, or location restricted by your administrator."

According to MS-Q&A by Limitless Technology.

The above error caused by a Conditional Access policy. Sometimes, specific account or system restrictions are required, such as preinstalled certificates, token USB keys, or geographical location, to log in successfully.

You can check with the administrator of tenant or you can get list of conditional access policy by PowerShell command.
Command:
Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy
Id                      : 6b5e999b-0ba8-4186-a106-e0296c1c4358
DisplayName             : Demo app for documentation
CreatedDateTime         : 2019-09-26T23:12:16.0792706Z
ModifiedDateTime        : 2019-09-27T00:12:12.5986473Z
State                   : Disabled
          

To remove conditional access policy you can use the below command:
Command:
Remove-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -PolicyId  6b5e999b-0ba8-418xxxxxx6c1c4358

Reference:
Troubleshooting sign-in problems with Conditional Access - Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft Learn
